# Iterator Pattern implemented inside of Composite Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, iterator, composite

I am working on a project for Design Patterns, and I am trying to implement an iterator within my composite base class. The problem though is that I am getting errors from the compiler not knowing what the symbol T is. I am using generics in the interface for my iterator.

Here is my code for the Iterator interface:

```
interface Iter<T> {
  public void first();
  public void next();
  public boolean isDone();
  public T currentItem();
}
```

And here is my code for the Composite base class:

```
abstract class Composite extends Component {

  public Iter<T> makeIter() {
    return new Iter<T>() {
      private Component component = Composite.this;
      private int _count = 0;

      public void first() {
        // position the iterator to the first element
        _count = 0;
      }

      public void next() {
        // advances the current element
        _count += 1;
      }

      public boolean isDone() {
        // returns true if iterator has cycled all the way through
        return _count >= component.getSize();
      }

      public Component currentItem() {
        // returns current item iterator is positioned on
        return component.getChild(_count);
      }
    };
  }

  //abstract primitive methods to implement
  @Override
  public abstract Component getChild(int number);
  @Override
  protected abstract void doAdd(Component part);
  @Override
  protected abstract void doRemove(Component part);


}
```

Code for Component:

```
abstract class Component {
  //member variables, in this case a reference to parent
  private Component parent = null;
  protected int instanceID = 0;

  //composite methods
  final public Component add(Component part) {
    try {
      // let composites define how children are managed
      doAdd(part);

      // set this Component as the parent of the added part
      part.parent = this;
    } catch(RuntimeException e) {
      throw e;
    }
    return this;
  }

  final public Component remove(Component part) {
    try {
      // let composites define how children are managed
      doRemove(part);

      //remove this Component as the parent of the added parent
      part.parent = null;
    } catch(RuntimeException e) {
      throw e;
    }
    return this;
  }

  protected Component getParent() {
    return parent;
  }

  // Methods that Composites need to Override
  abstract public Iter<T> makeIter();

  public int getSize() {
    return 1;
  }

  public Component getChild(int number) {
    return null;
  }

  protected void doAdd(Component part) {
    throw new RuntimeException("add() not supported");
  }

  protected void doRemove(Component part) {
    throw new RuntimeException("remove() not supported");
  }

  //toString
  final public String toString() {
    return (parent == null) ?
      instanceID + " is the root." :
      instanceID + " is the child of " + parent;
  }
}
```

Here is the error message that I am getting:

```
Component.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
  abstract public Iter<T> makeIter();
                   ^
  symbol:   class T
  location: class Component
Composite.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
  public Iter<T> makeIter() {
```

I am not a 100% sure I am implementing this in the right way, but I know that for the project we need to implement the iterator within the composite base class. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what is a `Component`?

Comment: I added the code for Component

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing Composite Pattern with an Iterator Pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39991800/implementing-composite-pattern-with-an-iterator-pattern)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Iter<T>` defines a generic type `T`, which is fine for the abstract case, but your `Composite` class is using a specific type, `Component`, which needs to be declared:

```
public Iter<Component> makeIter() {
  return new Iter<Component>() {
    ...
  }
}
```

The same goes for your `Component` class:

```
abstract public Iter<Component> makeIter();
```

Comment: What should I do with the method makeIter()in my Component class, because I'm getting an error that it cannot find symbol for T.

Comment: Yeah it compiles now with no problems! Thank you so much for the help.